# How to apply a class to a svg onclick?

Tags: css, svg

i have an svg for which onclick the color of the svg (should change to white) and the container (icon_container) that holds it should change to blue. how can i do it. Below is the code snippet,

```
state = {
  active: false,
};

click = () => {
  this.setState({active: !this.state.active});
};

render = () => {
  const classes = ['icon_container'];
  if (this.state.active) {
    classes.push('active');
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.join(' ')}>
      <SvgLayer className="icon" onClick={this.click}/>
    </div>
  );
};

icons {
  margin-top: 16px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  right: 16px;

  .icon_container {
    background-color: white;

    .icon {
      height: 16px;
      width: 16px;

      * {
        fill: blue;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

i have tried something like below to change svg color to white and icon_container to blue... but doesnot work.

```
.active.icons.icon_container {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: please create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: This is fairly simple to accomplish, however it would be super helpful to see what code the `< SvgLayer/>` component returns.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-3ukhys)

Answer (score 0):

html:

in the body above the use of the svg put your svg into the html, eg:

insert this svg use where you want to use it:

```
<svg id="icon-svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
    <use xlink:href="#icon"></use>
</svg>
```

css:
set the colour:

```
#icon-svg use
{
    fill: #000;
}
```

change the colour on hover:

```
#icon-svg use:hover, 
#icon-svg use:active, 
#icon-svg use:focus
{
    fill: #fff;
}
```

Helpful link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/use